# In Android multiplayer, which override is called when an invitation is accepted?

Tags: android, google-play-games

I have implemented the multi player feature in my game. when I click the "Invite friends" button, I am redirected the the screen to invite my friends. The invitation goes and by the time my friends respond, if I navigate away from the screen that shows the list of friends, then which override is called when the invitation that I sent is accepted.

I wanted to go to that override and start my game. Else the person who accepted the game starts the game, but i am not able to start my game.

Answer (score 0):

The [RoomUpdateListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RoomUpdateListener.html) interface defines the callbacks for client state changes.

You might want to look at the [ButtonClicker](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/ButtonClicker) sample which is a real-time multiplayer game.

The basic flow is:
1. Build the room including the invited players and call `Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.create(mGoogleApiClient, rtmConfigBuilder.build());`

2. Once the room is created, [onRoomCreated](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RoomUpdateListener.html#onRoomCreated(int, com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.Room)) is called, indicating if the room was created successfully.  In this method is a good time to show the waiting room UI until all the players are connected.  The waiting room is shown by getting the intent and starting it.  See [getWaitingRoomIntent](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RealTimeMultiplayer.html#getWaitingRoomIntent(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient, com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.Room, int))
3. Once all the players are connected,  the waiting room activity will finish, and onActivityResult will be called.  From there you can start your  gameplay.

If you don't want to use the waiting room, you can implement the [RoomStatusUpdateListener.onPeersConnected](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RoomStatusUpdateListener.html#onPeersConnected(com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.Room, java.util.List)) and related methods to determine when to start playing.